# Retornar y usar formato JSON con FLask

Tags: python, json, flask

Estoy desarrollando mi proyecto de grado con flask y una raspberry pi, mi aplicación python recoge un JSON de Openweather y lo intento mostrar en una vista, pero me devuelve un mensaje que dice lo siguiente:

```
<Response 813 bytes [200 OK]>
```

No como usar exactamente el JSON con flask pero el codigo de app.py es el siguiente:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, jsonify
import requests
import json



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/weather/actual')
def weather():
    api_address='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Cochabamba,bo&APPID=fa24732182de2d47f48bb1578fa4cf78'
    url = api_address
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    temp_actual = json_data["main"]["temp"]
    return render_template('ch1.html', temp = jsonify({"weather" : json_data}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host = '0.0.0.0')
```

Y el codigo de ch1.html es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sistema de Monitoreo Remoto</title>
    <!-- Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Manjari&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- CSS
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}">
    -->


</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ temp }}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo jsonify a un atributo a un objeto, te recomiendo devolver `return render_template('ch1.html', temp=json_data)` en caso de querer usar la variable weather en tu plantilla enviarlo de esta manera  `return render_template('ch1.html', temp={'weather':json_data})` ya que lo que haces al indicar jsonify es enviar la clase request a tu plantilla.